# Magento webservice rest limit call

Tags: rest, magento, magento-1.7

I have a RESTful custom webservice and that needs limit the number of calls made at the same time (because the answer can be very long given the number of products to be returned in any given call). How do I go about putting this limitation in place?

Comment: We need more details about how you implemented this, and what you've tried to rate-limit API calls?

Comment: I created a class model which inherits of Mage_Api2_Model_Resource
with function getRenderer()    _render()   ...
I wants that if we call my webservice and what it is already in the course of execution, it render an error message xml.